# Heat Conduction 2D Fourier libmesh / deal.II

Tags: c++, math, physics, transfer

are there any examples of solving heat conduction problems in 2D with fourier's law as main equation with finite elements and using either libmesh or deal.II libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2D heat equation is the only way to solve heat conduction problems.  Lots of examples using finite difference, finite element, and boundary element methods.  All require meshes of some kind.  Which one do you want to apply?

OK, so now we know you want to solve 2D heat conduction problems using FEA.  It's a three step process:

1. Pre-process (create the mesh for your geometry, apply material properties, boundary conditions, and initial conditions (if transient or non-linear).
2. Perform the analysis (formulate and solve the matrix equations for node and element unknowns).
3. Post-process (graphical display of results is best, since pictures are worth thousands of words).

Which solver do you wish to use?  Is your objective to write one or just use one?  Do you want open source?  Must it be written in C++?  (Not likely.  FORTRAN is by far the most common language for such programs.)

Is yours a large problem?  I'm guessing no, but massive parallelization might be of interest to you:

http://www.cas.usf.edu/~cconnor/parallel/2dheat/2dheat.html

[FEMHub](http://www.femhub.org/) likes Python, probably because of the nice libraries NumPy and SciPy.

Here's a [site](http://www.mechanicalengineeringblog.com/1757-finite-element-analysis-fea-list-of-fea-softwares-list-of-open-source-softwares-list-of-commercial-softwares/) that lists open source libraries for Java.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  There's only one equation for heat conduction in solids: the diffusion equation.  What physics are you proposing instead?

Comment: Ah, never mind, it was just the grammar of your answer made me think you'd missed a "not" out.  It's a long time since I studied thermodynamics!

Comment: Heat conduction isn't a part of studying thermodynamics; it's more properly part of heat transfer.  I've studied both extensively.  Thanks for playing.

Comment: Meh, I was taught it in thermodynamics course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I would like to use finite elements and these libs.

Comment: I have no limitations as far as the library is concerned or the language although I would prefer something in either C or Java.
Plus it must be an opensource one, currently I am using an old version of comsol.
Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI, [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183751/how-can-we-execute-c-program-what-are-the-steps#comment19658760_14183775) wasn't "trollish" (as you call it). I was asking you questions to guide you to a correct answer, but if you want to take it as that, be my guest. Sometimes you teach, sometimes you need to be taught. Apparently, if someone teaches you something, you immediately assume they're trolling. That's just sad.

Comment: Whatever.  Are the steps I listed incorrect, besides the file types?  Got a problem with those?  Is it likely that if the OP was creating those source files with Visual Studio that they'd be named .cpp?  And is it likely that someone who had to ask this question would knowingly override the defaults?  I get tired of people like you who nitpic without offering much of value on their own.  By all means, posts an answer that contradicts mine or improves on it.  Nobody can vote your comments up or down.

Comment: Aren't there any implemented examples on this subject?

Comment: Plenty.  This is very much a "solved" problem.  You ought to be able to find some without too much trouble.  I've already spent enough time on your problem.  I'm finished now.